# JQuery toggleClass() affecting nested list

Tags: html, jquery

I am using JQuery so when I toggle my parent link in my vertical navigation, basically it opens the sub list with a arrow pointing down on clicked. The problem I have is when the list is clicked, and I click on the sub list links, and arrow appears on those too. I just want it too appear on a parent element only. How can I achieve this?

This is my CSS code:

```
.sidebar-category li > a:before {
    color: #ffffff;
    content: '► ';
}

.sidebar-category li > a:only-child:before {
    content: ' ';
}

.sidebar-category li.clicked > a:before {
    color: #ff0000;
    content: '▼ ';
}
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".sidebar-category > li").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find("ul").fadeToggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('.sidebar-category > li').click(function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
    }); 

});
```

And my HTML is just a standard nested list.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: its abit complicated because my nav is generated dynamically and i have so much styling involved, i just really want to know how to make that toggleClass() not affect the nested list but only the parent list on click

Comment: Why isn't the $(this).toggleClass('clicked') in the same ".click" listeners than the rest of it? You only need one listener... And $(this).find('ul') will find all nested UL in the current "li", you might want to try "$(this).CHILDREN('ul')".  Without a jsFiddle or the HTML structure I cant help you more than that